# Using Distinct and MAX(date) in a large data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table that stores the list of users who have accessed a product(with the accessed date).
I have written the below query to get the list of users who have accessed the product B between '2021-02-01' and '2021-02-26'.

`SELECT DISTINCT UserName,Country,ADate,Product FROM Report WHERE UserName != '-'  and Product='B and (CAST(ADate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate  AND @enddate '`

then it gives the below result:

```
UserName Country    ADate                 Product
-------- ------    --------              ---------
asson     IN    2021-02-10 00:00:00.000     B
rajan     US    2021-02-23 00:00:00.000     B
rajan     US    2021-02-25 00:00:00.000     B
moody     US    2021-02-14 00:00:00.000     B
rajon     US    2021-02-01 00:00:00.000     B
lukman    US    2021-02-10 00:00:00.000     B
```

since the user rajan has accessed the product in 2 days it shows 2 entries for rajan even though I have added distinct. So I have modified the query as below:

`SELECT DISTINCT UserName,Country,max(ADate),Product FROM Report WHERE UserName != '-'  and Product='B' and (CAST(ADate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate  AND @enddate group by Username,product`

 This query gives me the required result. But the problem I am facing now is When I select the table with more than a month gap (say data between 2 months), I miss some data in the output. I believe it might be due to the `MAX(ADate)`. Can anyone give a good suggestion to get rid of this issue?

Comment: _written the below query to get the list of users_ Nope, you are getting the rows for accesses. If you word your goal correctly, you will often find a path to your goal more easily. It seems you want the most recent row per user - or perhaps the most recent row per user and month? Try web search for "first in group"

Comment: @SMor: Updated the query. I am looking for users who accessed the product B within <startdate> and <enddate>

Comment: Then add at least one row that does not fall within the same month as all your other data, add sample parameters that both over single month period and a multi-month period as well as the expected results. Mind-reading doesn't work so well at a distance. Perhaps explain why you need to cast ADate. Better would be to provide a script containing DDL and sample data.

Comment: And your second query does nothing but generate an error - you cannot include Country in the select list without including it in the GROUP BY clause (or using an aggregate on it).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the latest access date of each user by month

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserName,Country, month(ADate) as month, max(ADate),Product FROM Report WHERE UserName != '-'  and Product='B' group by UserName, Country, month, Product
```